# How do I convert this nested for loop to a map or list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Note: this is a working program, I just need to make it faster.
This is the nested for loop:

```
taf = []
for i in range(len(piou)):
    counter = 0
    for j in range(len(piou[i])):
        
        if piou[i][j] == True:
            counter = counter + 1
    if counter == len(piou[i]):
        taf.append(i)
```

I tried doing this:

```
taf = [i for i in range(len(piou))
       if counter == len(piou[i])
       for j in range(len(piou[i]))
       if piou[i][j] == True]
```

but I can't figure out how to put the `counter` variable in between along with its increment.

Note: `piou` is a 2D tensor with boolean values and I am trying to find and append all the rows (`i`) index values to `taf` list which have all "true" column values.

piou looks like this:

```
tensor([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: This is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should tell us what you are *actually*  trying to do (including a small example of what is in `piou`. I suspect you are just trying to do: `[i for i, sublist in enumerate(piou) if all(sublist)]`, but since you haven't mentioned the actual goal, that's just a guess.

Comment: @Mark I am sorry that I forgot to write what I was trying to do. I have updated now

Comment: Still no example data to test with...

Comment: @KellyBundy how about now?

Comment: `NameError: name 'tensor' is not defined`

Comment: @KellyBundy In my code piou is a tensor. you can put 
`[[ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]`
in piou named list and then convert it to a tensor using this:
`piou= torch.FloatTensor(piou)
 piou=piou.to(device='cuda')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop where you're just incrementing a number can be replaced with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), but where that summation is just going to be compared with the length of the list, use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

As well, avoid `for i in range(len(seq)) ... i, seq[i]`, use `for i, x in enumerate(seq)` instead.

```
taf = [i for i, row in enumerate(piou) if all(row)]
```